# Search linked list with two pointers

Tags: c, search, linked-list

I'm currently writing a task for uni trying read in a data from either a file or stdin, tokenising allt the words and presenting a list of occurring words and the count of each word.

Example of desired output:

```
Good bye occurred 5 times
This occurred 3 times
Hello occurred 1 time
```

Example of current output:

```
This
1
is
1
fun!

1
This
1
is
1
fun!
```

Don't mind the formatting of the output. That is an issue to be fixed later.

I have a running program that uses a linked list declared as follows:

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[50];
    int count;
    struct node * next;
}words;
```

The linked list is initialised as follows

```
words * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(words));
```

And two pointers assigned to the list

```
words * current = head;
words * search = head;
```

What I'm struggling with is the following piece of code:

```
while (!feof(input_file))
{
    while(current->next != NULL)
    {
        current = current-> next;
    }

    //Test-loop for tokenisation
    while(fgets(buffer,512, input_file) != NULL)
    {
        //Declaration of char token
        char* token;

        //Declaration of flag
        int duplicate_word = 1;
        //Test for-loop
        for (token = strtok(buffer, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " "))
        {
            char duplication_check_token[60];
            strcpy(duplication_check_token, token);

            while(search != NULL)
            {
                char duplication_check_search[60];
                strcpy(duplication_check_search, current -> word);
                if (strcmp(duplication_check_search, duplication_check_token) == 0)
                {
                    search->count++;
                    duplicate_word = 0;
                    break;
                }
                search = search -> next;
            }

            if (duplicate_word != 0)
            {
                while(current->next != NULL)
                {
                    current = current-> next;

                }

                current = malloc(sizeof(words));
                strcpy(current -> word, token);
                current -> count = 1;
                current -> next = NULL;

                //Test print
                printf("%s\n", token);
                printf("%d\n", current -> count);
            }

        }



    }
```

When debugging, it never seems to check through the entire linked list in the `while(search != NULL)`loop.

What part of the logic am I getting wrong?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: See [Why is `while(!foef(..))` always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You have a break condition in your loop that is probably the reason why you dont go through all your list. So it means you have a duplicate in your list.

Add this before the loop:

```
int a = 0;
```

And then add the commented lines in the loop:

```
++a; // before the if.
if (strcmp(duplication_check_search, duplication_check_token) == 0)
{
    search->count++;
    duplicate_word = 0;
    printf("%d\n", a); // to check what was the index of the item causing the break
    getchar(); // pause until next keypress
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For two reasons.  Firstly, `search` is only ever initialised to the head of the list once, when it is declared, so it never sees the words that might be added to the head of the list.  I think this:

```
        while(search != NULL)
        {
            char duplication_check_search[60];
            strcpy(duplication_check_search, current -> word);
            if (strcmp(duplication_check_search, duplication_check_token) == 0)
            {
                search->count++;
                duplicate_word = 0;
                break;
            }
            search = search -> next;
        }
```

should probably be this:

```
        for (search = head; search != NULL; search = search->next)
        {
            char duplication_check_search[60];
            strcpy(duplication_check_search, current -> word);
            if (strcmp(duplication_check_search, duplication_check_token) == 0)
            {
                search->count++;
                duplicate_word = 0;
                break;
            }
         }
```

And secondly, because there is only the one `head` element in the list!  Your code allocates a `word` struct and assigns it to `current`, but `current` is never inserted into your list.  I think this:

```
            while(current->next != NULL)
            {
                current = current-> next;

            }

            current = malloc(sizeof(words));
            strcpy(current -> word, token);
            current -> count = 1;
            current -> next = NULL;
```

was meant to be this:

```
            current = malloc(sizeof(words));
            strcpy(current -> word, token);
            current -> count = 1;
            current -> next = head;
            head = current;
```

the `while (current...` loop isn't necessary, it's far easier to add new elements to the head of the list.

Also, I trust that you realise that if a line in your file has a "word" more than fifty characters long, really really bad things will happen, right?  You might want to use `strncpy()` rather than `strcpy()`.